# How shadowsocks-android installed share to other?

Tags: android

A android phone installed shadowsocks app,then,how to share to other phone or computer?Like fqrouter2 HTTP Proxy,It can use HTTP Proxy to share to others!So,In shadowsocks-android?
ths y help!

Answer (score 0):

Config your local port for the LAN users, default 1080. Users in the LAN have set their proxy seting to you IP:port.
Pc client support pac which is optional proxy, I don't know, the mobile client support.

Answer (score 0):

You must use NAT mode,then share your phone network via wlan/usb/bluetooth,set the proxy option to (your phone ip):(your local port).